# Display user information with Strapi and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, strapi

I take the liberty of contacting you because I am trying to display the user information (after logging in) but I have an error. I think I have to allow this (already checked on strapi) but I don't know how.

Thanking you in advance

My error : **GET http://localhost:1337/api/users/me 401 (Unauthorized)**

code : ` const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:1337/api/users/me')
      
      .then(({ data }) => setUsers(data.data))
      .catch((error) => setError(error))
  }, [])

  


  if (error) {
    // Print errors if any
    return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following: *how does Strapi know which user you want to retrieve the details for?*

You need to pass an `Authorization: Bearer <user-token-here>` with your request. Moreover, make sure that the `/me` endpoint is available for users with the `authenticated` role (settings > user-permissions > roles)